# Using multiple awaits within a Promise that are dependent on each other

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, async-await, es6-promise

Before describing the issue in a very complex way, I would like to know how to execute multiple dependent awaits in a `return Promise` one after another without getting new data in my `return Promise` block. In other words, I just want my try-block to be executed as one statement.

```js
const handler = (payload) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const exists = await getRedis(payload)
      if(exists === null) {
        await setRedis(payload)
        await write2Mongo(payload)
        resolve()
      } else {
        resolve()
      }
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err)
    }
  });
};
```

In concrete terms, it's about RabbitMQ ("amqplib": "^0.8.0"), where the payloads fly in. These I want to check first if they are known by the system. If not, I want to set them in Redis ("async-redis": "^2.0.0") and then write them to MongoDB ("mongoose": "^6.0.9"). Since I get a lot of messages from RabbitMQ, it works fine at first and then I get a "duplicate key error" from Mongo. This is because my first getRedis returns a null. While writing the data into Redis and MongoDB, a second message comes into my block and gets a "null" value from getRedis, because the message was not yet set via setRedis.

As I read, this is an antipattern with bad error handling. But the corresponding posts have unfortunately not solved my problem.

Can you please help me.

Comment: You don't need the promise constructor to wrap something that already returns a promise.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Let's assume

getRedis needs 1 second
setRedis needs 3 seconds
write2Mongo needs 5 seconds

A message arrives and getRedis needs 1 second for it. The if statement is executed and setRedis takes 3 seconds to write. In the meantime another message arrives at getRedis and gets the value null, because setRedis has not written this ID yet and passes this information to write2Mongo, which throws a duplicate key error, because it was written before.

I need a way that getRedis doesn't get another message until setRedis and write2Mongo are done.

Answer (score 1):

in senario that you describe, you want a queue that you can process it in series

```
let payloads = [];
const handler = payload => payloads.push(payload);


;(async function insertDistincPayloads() {
  for (let i=0; i < payloads.length; i++) {
    const exists = await getRedis(payload)
    if(exists === null) {
      await setRedis(payload)
      await write2Mongo(payload)
    }
  }
  payloads = []
  setTimeout(insertDistincPayloads, 100); // loop continuously with a small delay
})();
```

sorry for my bad english :-)